# $\forall x\in[a,b],\;M(x)\in O_{2n+1}(\Bbb R)$. Why is $M'(x)$ non-invertible?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $M$ be a function from $[a ; b]$ to $M_{2n+1}(\mathbb{R})$, of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ such that:
$$\forall x \in[a ; b], { }^t M(x) \cdot M(x) = I_n.
$$
I want to show that:
$$\forall x \in [a ; b], M^{\prime}(x) \notin GL_{2n+1}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Starting by taking the derivative, I get:

$$\forall x \in [a ; b], { }^tM(x)M^{\prime} (x)+ { }^tM^{\prime}(x)M(x)=0.
$$

Any help!

Comment: How did you arrive at your derivative?

Comment: For families $A(x), B(x)$ of operators we have for fixed $x$ $$A(x+h)B(x+h)=(A(x)+hA'(x)+o(h))(B(x)+hB'(x)+o(h))=A(x)B(x)+h(A'(x)B(x)+A(x)B'(x))+o(h).$$ Thus, $$(A(x)B(x))'=A'(x)B(x)+A(x)B'(x).$$

Comment: Will that be true though? Consider the simplest case of a rotation by an angle $x$. Would the derivative of that respect your condition?

Comment: Yes, sorry I knew the derivative.. Unfortunately I didn't write it correctly in latex. I will modify it!

Comment: What about taking the determinant of your relation?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307591/derivative-of-orthogonal-matrix-generalization-of-frenet-frame-equations) you can see one can write $M'(t)=A(t)M(t)$, where $A(t)$ is antisymmetric $\forall t\in I$.

Taking the determinant:

$$\det \left( M'(t)\right)=\det\left(A(t)\right)\det\left(M(t)\right)=\pm\det\left(A(t)\right)$$

For an $n\times n$ antisymmetric matrix $A$, we have $n=1[2]\implies \det\left(A(t)\right)=0$, thus $M'$ is singular for odd $n$.

Comment: That's great. One last Qst: why did you consider $det(M(t))=1$, I think it may be $-1$. I know that it will not change the rest of the proof..

Comment: @Motaka Indeed, I forgot to write the $\pm$